# Disable @ char in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have the following sign up the layout in my application:

[image]

I found out that for some reason users sometimes insert in the Name field their email and then instead of their name the email is shown in the application.

I had like to avoid this situation and to disable the @ char in this EditText or more generally I don't want them to write their email there.

How can I do it?

I don't mind them inserting anything else including chars/numbers/symbols/any language.

Thank you

Comment: Use `TextChangedListener` to watch for text change events on the EditText and validate the text the user is inputting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, it's better to have a field validation when the user clicks on the Login button instead of « blocking » the user when writing data.

Doing this, you can display an error message to warn the user.

Comment: It'll be better if you'll create some validate method, instead of blocking users iteraction

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out some input; you can do it by attaching an InputFilter to your EditText.

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
InputFilter inputFilter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
            if(source.charAt(i) == '@'){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "\"@\" is not allowed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //We are returning empty to ignore "@" character.
                return "";
            }
        }
        //Otherwise we can return null to leave everything as it is.
        return null;
    }
};
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{inputFilter});
```